# Unable to push to Bitbucket from Sourcetree without Error

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I've been using Sourcetree and Bitbucket for a number of years. Recently things have changed and I'm a bit lost. I'm getting this message

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags the_repo refs/heads/file_system:refs/heads/file_system 
Pushing to https://BLAH@bitbucket.org/BLAH/the_repo.git
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://BLAH@bitbucket.org/BLAH/the_repo.git/'
Pushing to https://BLAH@bitbucket.org/BLAH/the_repo.git
POST git-receive-pack (549 bytes)
remote: 
remote: Create pull request for file_system:        
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/BLAH/the_repo/pull-requests/new?source=file_system&t=1        
remote: 
To https://bitbucket.org/BLAH/the_repo.git
 = [up to date]      The_Repo-Release-Version-123 -> The_Repo-Release-Version-123
   27a5475..71431a7  file_system -> file_system
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/The_Repo/file_system'
Completed successfully
```

But it appears the push is actually happening despite the error. Thinking I would be better dealing with the error condition I went into Bitbucket.org and looked for the password to set. I setup an App Password for my repo in Bitbucket to allow two-step authentication (was this the right one to set?). According to the Bitbucket page

> App passwords allow two-step verification users to access their
>   Bitbucket account through apps such as SourceTree.

I'm not sure if this is what was meant by the first message but this was the only place I could find that seemed relevant. Things, however, didn't change. The 'push' seems to take a bit longer but still goes through. I get an identical message including the error and 'completed successfully'. Could anyone please tell me how to fix the "Invalid username or password" error and maybe where I am supposed to put the password both in Bitbucket and Sourcetree? Perhaps the problem is that I am using Sourcetree and this is just complicating my life. Would you suggest I just learn the command line and deal with pushes from there?

Comment: I'd always recommend using the commandline over any GUI client for Git, but the push should work just fine. If you created an app password for bitbucket and set this password as password for your bitbucket account in Sourcetree, then the push should work fine. Did you set that app password that you created as password for the bitbucket account in Sourcetree?

Comment: @Vampire Thanks for responding, the push does work - the files are up there - just getting the error message. Don't know where to set the App Password in Sourcetree and it is not being asked for when I do the push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enter you newly created App password in Sourcetree do the following:

1. Go to `Preferences -> Accounts`
2. Double-click on your Bitbucket account
3. Click `Set Password`

Comment: If I go to "Preferences>Accounts" I can double click the Bitbucket account and my Auth is set to OAth. If I change this to Basic I get a username and password field. Is this applicable?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know Sourcetree cannot work fine with two-factor authentication and you need to use an app password like that. Or maybe a newer version of Sourcetree fixes and properly supports it, I don't know. I don't use Sourcetree.

Comment: Now did it work or did it not work? What problem do you still have?

Comment: Not sure what your "read and obey" comment means? I accepted your answer to close this topic as I am finished with it. Your comment above about Sourcetree having problems with two-factor authentication is probably the most useful part of the information I have received from you on this. I have now un-ticked your answer as it does not actually answer my question but this will leave things unanswered so I assume I will get a prompt at some stage to do something further. My likely next step is to try out Tower and see if I can get my head around just doing this with the command line.

Comment: Why doesn't it answer your question? If you use an app password in Sourcetree, authentication should work fine without any errors. From the commandline you will have the same issue. Unless you authenticate via SSH keys which you can also do from Sourcetree as far as I can tell. The comment hinted you to a documentation page that tells you what you should do on helpful answers, which is up-voting, additionally to accpeting the correct answer.

Comment: But I already had the password set in Preferences>Accounts as was evidenced by the fact that my pushes were working. What I was trying to solve was the "authentication failed" error. I do appreciate your help and understand that this is a by-product of me trying to take a shortcut and avoid handling this stuff on the command line. To be honest git and its workings just bore me and I'd rather be coding ;-)

Comment: No, you didn't have any password set. You used OAuth as you stated yourself. When using OAuth you don't have any password set in Sourcetree. For this you have to switch to Basic Auth and use the App password as I advised.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144852/discussion-between-amergin-and-vampire).

Comment: I have now set Basic authentication and the push works fine with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Once you created your local repository:

1. click on the right top icon "settings" then create a remote branch "master"
2. After this branch is created.. you will be able to push.

I think it's new in Sourcetree.. I never had to do that before. Took me 2 days to find the answer.

I am on version : SourceTree version 2.3.5.0